# Error in : VisioForge.Shared.MediaFoundation.EVR.IMFVideoMixerControl2

Tags: c#, encryption, fullscreen, playback, renderer

When I want the video to be maximize: I get this error:

```
  Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'VisioForge.Shared.MediaFoundation.EVR.IMFVideoMixerControl2'.
  This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{8459616D-966E-4930-B658-54FA7E5A16D3}'
  failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)). "
```

The piece of code that causes an error :

```
    private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Stop the current playback
        mediaPlayer1.Stop();

        // Open a file dialog for selecting the encrypted file
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            Filter = "Encrypted Files (*.Enc)|*.Enc",
            Title = "Select Encrypted File"
        };

        // If the user selects an encrypted file
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string encryptedFilePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

            // Read the encrypted file into a byte array
            byte[] encryptedBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(encryptedFilePath);

            // Use MemoryStream to read the encrypted data
            using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedBytes))
            // Use Aes for decryption
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                byte[] iv = new byte[16];
                inputStream.Read(iv, 0, iv.Length);

                // Set the decryption key and initialization vector
                aesAlg.Key = encryptionKey;
                aesAlg.IV = iv;

                // Use MemoryStream to write the decrypted output
                using (MemoryStream decryptedStream = new MemoryStream())
                // Use CryptoStream for decryption
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(inputStream, aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    // Use Task.Run to perform potentially blocking operations on a separate thread
                    await Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        // Copy decrypted data from CryptoStream to MemoryStream
                        cryptoStream.CopyTo(decryptedStream);

                        // Reset the position to the beginning of the stream
                        decryptedStream.Position = 0;

                        // Create a ManagedIStream from the decrypted memory stream
                        ManagedIStream stream = new ManagedIStream(decryptedStream);

                        // Set the MediaPlayer source to the memory stream
                        mediaPlayer1.Source_Mode = VFMediaPlayerSource.Memory_DS;
                        mediaPlayer1.Source_Stream = stream;
                        mediaPlayer1.Source_Stream_Size = decryptedStream.Length;

                        mediaPlayer1.Source_Stream_VideoPresent = true;
                        mediaPlayer1.Source_Stream_AudioPresent = true;
                        mediaPlayer1.Audio_OutputDevice = "Default DirectSound Device";

                        // Choose video renderer based on availability
                        if (VideoCapture.Filter_Supported_EVR())
                        {
                            mediaPlayer1.Video_Renderer.Video_Renderer = VFVideoRenderer.EVR;
                        }
                        else if (VideoCapture.Filter_Supported_VMR9())
                        {
                            mediaPlayer1.Video_Renderer.Video_Renderer = VFVideoRenderer.VMR9;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mediaPlayer1.Video_Renderer.Video_Renderer = VFVideoRenderer.VideoRenderer;
                        }

                        // Reset the event before starting playback
                        playbackFinishedEvent.Reset();

                        // Subscribe to playback events
                        mediaPlayer1.OnStop += MediaPlayer1_OnStop;
                        mediaPlayer1.OnError += MediaPlayer1_OnError;

                        // Start playback
                        mediaPlayer1.Play();

                        // Block the execution until playback is finished or a timeout occurs
                        playbackFinishedEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)); // Adjust the timeout as needed
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```